# ML380 G6 P410i RAID controller not detected

Tags: raid

I have a DL380 G6 server With P410i Array controller (embedded) 256MB Cache, no battery

When I turn off the server, then turn on after ± 5 minutes, the RAID controller is not detected (not drives, the whole raid controller) I can't access even pressing F8. The only way that I found for RAID controller work is keeping the server on ± 10 minutes, then shutdown and turn on again. After that, RAID controller works fine. I can access it pressing F8, see drives, boot OS without problems.

I updated BIOS, P410i firmware, checked power and data cables and problem still occurs. Is the lack of cache battery causing this problem?

Firmware version

```
BIOS P62 05/21/2018
P410i 6.64
BACKPLANE 1.14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is a system board replacement or hardware replacement.
You can potentially use a PCIe card-based P410, but given the age of the equipment, it's best to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some capacitor is failing. However this is very old equipment and I would not use it for anything other than testing/learning.

Comment: This is absolutely a failing capacitor. Or more than one. At this late date they're probably leaking too. A hobbyist could clean the controller and recap it, but that's a bit outside our scope.